# Stream a collection and collect into multiple results depending on independent predicates

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I am staring at some imperative code which I am trying to convert to a purely functional style. 
Basically there is a iterative for-loop over `inputSet` in which I check 3 predicates and fill 3 `outputSets` depending on which predicate matches. The output sets can be overlapping. How can I do this in a pure functional way using Java 8 streams/map/filter/ etc.?

Comment: It would be nice to see the code in the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest solution (except leaving everything as is which is even easier) is to create three separate streams:

```
Set<MyObj> set1 = inputSet.stream().filter(pred1).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<MyObj> set2 = inputSet.stream().filter(pred2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<MyObj> set3 = inputSet.stream().filter(pred3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you have a List of predicates, you can create a corresponding List of sets as a result:

```
List<Predicate<MyObj>> predicates = Arrays.asList(pred1, pred2, pred3);
List<Set<MyObj>> result = predicates.stream()
        .map(pred -> inputSet.stream().filter(pred).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here the first set in the resulting list corresponds to the first predicate and so on.

If you really want to process your input in single pass (for whatever reason), you may write a special collector for this. Here's one which is quite universal:

```
public static <T, A, R> Collector<T, ?, List<R>> multiClassify(
        List<Predicate<T>> predicates, Collector<? super T, A, R> downstream) {
    Supplier<A> dsSupplier = downstream.supplier();
    BiConsumer<A, ? super T> dsAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    BinaryOperator<A> dsCombiner = downstream.combiner();

    Supplier<List<A>> supplier = () -> Stream.generate(dsSupplier)
            .limit(predicates.size()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    BiConsumer<List<A>, T> accumulator = (list, t) -> IntStream
            .range(0, predicates.size()).filter(i -> predicates.get(i).test(t))
            .forEach(i -> dsAccumulator.accept(list.get(i), t));

    BinaryOperator<List<A>> combiner = (l1, l2) -> IntStream.range(0, predicates.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> dsCombiner.apply(l1.get(i), l2.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Characteristics[] dsCharacteristics = downstream.characteristics().toArray(
            new Characteristics[0]);
    if (downstream.characteristics().contains(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH)) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Collector<T, ?, List<R>> result = (Collector<T, ?, List<R>>) (Collector<T, ?, ?>) 
            Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, dsCharacteristics);
        return result;
    }
    Function<A, R> dsFinisher = downstream.finisher();
    Function<List<A>, List<R>> finisher = l -> l.stream().map(dsFinisher)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher, dsCharacteristics);
}
```

It takes a list of predicates and returns list of downstream collector results for each predicate. Usage example:

```
List<String> input = asList("abc", "ade", "bcd", "cc", "cdac");

List<Predicate<String>> preds = asList(
        s -> s.length() == 3, 
        s -> s.startsWith("a"), 
        s -> s.endsWith("c"));
List<Set<String>> result = input.stream().collect(multiClassify(preds, Collectors.toSet()));
// [[bcd, abc, ade], [abc, ade], [cc, abc, cdac]]
```

Comment: The first is trivial . It is streaming multiple times. I want to stream only once (the imperative way is O(n)). The second falls short because the one stream item may be in multiple rset. I think the correct way would be to collect it a map of predicate vs setOfResult that matches . I think I may have my answer , still waiting for better answers.

Comment: I hit a problem related to this .When I get back the result I lose info about which list was for which predicate . How can I adapt the universal meta collector to return a List<Map<Predicate , Set<String>>> ?

Comment: @Asterisk, You can zip the resulting list with the predicate list (like `IntStream.range(0, preds.size()).boxed().collect(toMap(preds::get, result::get))`). However I don't like using functions as map keys. This is quite fragile as function object identity is a dubious thing.

Comment: @TagirValeev Nice post, but I'm curious about a syntax detail. Could you please explain the double cast in this line `Collector<T, ?, List<R>> result = (Collector<T, ?, List<R>>) (Collector<T, ?, ?>) 
            Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, dsCharacteristics)`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, direct cast (without intermediate `(Collector<T, ?, ?>)`) causes compilation error. Probably there's easier way to overcome this, but I don't know it...

Comment: I'm often faced with the same dilemma. And until now I've always chosen for the first solution for the sake of readability. Yes, the complexity is changing from O(n) to O(cn) (where c is the number of lists you want to create), but that's still linear asumming that c is fixed. In practice this hasn't resulted in any performance issues. Even if it did, the performance improvements gained from refactoring existing loops far outweigh the performance loss for these few imperitive loops where you need multiple lists as output.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach would be to use the [`Consumer.andThen(anotherConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#andThen-java.util.function.Consumer-) method to create a composed consumer made of inner consumers that execute *in sequence*. Each one of these inner consumers would test every predicate and classify elements depending on whether they match or not.

```
public static <T> Consumer<T> classify(Predicate<T> predicate, Consumer<T> action) {
    return elem -> Optional.ofNullable(elem)
        .filter(predicate)
        .ifPresent(action);
}
```

This utility method returns a consumer that will execute the given action on the element being consumed, as long as the predicate returns `true` for the element.

Test:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

Set<Integer> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<Integer> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<Integer> set3 = new LinkedHashSet<>();

// Here's the composed consumer, made of inner consumers
Consumer<Integer> multiClassifier = classify(n -> n % 2 == 0, set1::add)
        .andThen(classify(n -> n % 3 == 0, set2::add))
        .andThen(classify(n -> n % 5 == 0, set3::add));

// Here the stream is consumed by the composed consumer
stream.forEach(multiClassifier);
```

Each inner consumer is created with the utility method defined above, which receives an independent predicate that, when matched, will add the element of the stream to the given set, i.e. if the element of the stream is a multiple of 3, it will be added to `set2`.

At the end, the stream is consumed with this composed consumer and thus the stream is classified by independent predicates:

```
System.out.println(set1); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
System.out.println(set2); // [3, 6, 9, 12]
System.out.println(set3); // [5, 10]
```

Comment: This is quite nice and simple. However it is accessing sets (local variables) and mutating them and is deceptively compositional (not pure).

Comment: @Asterisk Accessing and mutating local variables, agreed. (I don't think this is much of a problem, it's just not as elegant as a collector). I don't get why it's deceptively compositional, though.

Comment: Well consumer is generally the last operation in steams processing  , so I retract that part :)

Comment: @Asterisk You know, in order to make it look more functional, you could write the same code in one line, except for the three sets declaration. I know you want a purely functional style, so I must warn you... Beware of collectors, as they could be deceptive in that matter :) I mean they perform a *mutable reduction*, mutable being the key part here. `collect()` returns a data structure, but the reduction is not performed in a purely functional style, since partial collection results are accumulated and combined in the data structure on every reduction step, i.e. holding state.

Comment: I like this one, it's readable and only iterates over the the list once, but shouldn't this work out of the box since the latest java LTS versions?

Comment: @Lusk116 I don't get your question regarding latest java LTS versions. There are more collectors and more operations can be done on a stream, also there are records, type pattern matching, more methods in Optional, etc, but I don't see a way other than this or the custom collector