# Java 8 how to filter to two different lists?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have code looking something like this

```
List<MyObj> objs = ... // <- lot of objs

List<MyObj> objsThatAreA = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyObj> objsThatAreB = new ArrayList<>();

for (MyObj obj : objs) {
    if (isA(obj)){
        objsThatAreA .add(obj);
    } else if isB(obj))
        objsThatAreB.add(obj);
    }
    // Others are "discarded" Can be C,D,E and so on, but all are exclusive, can only be in one state. 
}
```

I would want to refactor into something like this

```
// Can this be done O(n)?
Stream<MyObj> objStream  = objs.stream();
Stream<MyObj> objsThatAreA = objStream.filter(o -> isA(i));
Stream<MyObj> objsThatAreB = objStream.filter(o -> isB(i));
```

My question is, in the second much more readable example, I iterate objs twice. Is there some way to achieve the same result in one pass using streams?

Key question is if it is possible to keep it O(n) and not O(2n) or O(cN) where c are all possible states (~14)

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407001/stream-a-collection-and-collect-into-multiple-results-depending-on-independent-p) solves your issue?

Comment: I would just `Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> collect = objs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass))`

Comment: The accepted answer of the question to which this one was marked as duplicate is not 100% clear on that the first part of the answer does not address "_Is there some way to achieve the same result in one pass using streams?_". While you can write it on one line, the accepted answer still does one pass over the input list per predicate.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. In this question pedicates are excusive (there's an else), while in the referenced question if statements are independent.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner That is true but in the refactored code using `filter` by the OP, the else part is dropped. Maybe a further clarification is needed.

Comment: @Tunaki You're right, I focused on the loop and ifs, but the refactored code is not functionally equivalent to the original code. Besides, he's wrongly unzipping the streams by means of an assignment (i.e. reusing the original stream) and this will lead to an exception. The original code can be easily refactored with `Collectors.groupingBy()`, or even better with a `forEach()` and a consumer with an if inside.